# Google AdWords have flagged my site as containing malware

Tags: google-search-console, redirects, google-ads, malware

However, there Webmaster Tools does not - and never has. And we have never had a message via Webmaster Tools or Analytics that we have malware.

To quote Google:

> [The Malware Team] have looked at the most recent scan and have
>   found that your site is not actually clean. You are using a redirect
>   on your landing page which is the site that is causing the problem.

And then I am advised to:

> Check your site request logs to find the bad domain and resolve the issue.

What should I look for in my request logs, has anyone else experienced a similar situation?

Obviously as far as I am aware we have no malware, we had a couple of redirects in htaccess but they were not on landing/homepage and have were just normal redirects that have not caused a problem elsewhere (and are now removed). It's a WordPress site.

Comment: pretty impossible to answer without more details or the url.  Although it seems likely that google are right.

Comment: @JamesRyan www.asla.co.uk

Comment: Is this the url under adwords though? Doesn't seem to redirect unless that is agent/geo specific.

Comment: we have no redirects anywhere on our site ! Google wont tell us which url is causign the problem. I think they have screwed up as don't understand why adwords says one thing and the web master tools say somethign different.

Comment: no kind of domain name forwarding with your dns?

Comment: @JamesRyan Ahhhhhhh. Not sure will check.

Comment: FWIW it looks like this is resolved in the meantime.

Answer (score 1):

Some time it happens that the website get infected by malicious activities and we are not aware of it. Try using some anti-malware scan utilities and find out malicious code that may be inserted on your website.

I had a client who faced the same problem and we found some `<iframe>` that was inserted by someone on his WordPress website. We removed that `<iframe>` and filed re-inclusion request in Google Webmaster Tool. It started working fine in 2 days.